# Where does the ['boo there'] come from in this code example?

Tags: python

I have this function here and I am struggling to figure out how the output is derived from this. Any help would be appreciated. thank you!

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: [str]):
        self._foo = a
        self._bar = b

    def get_foo(self):
        return self._foo

    def get_bar(self):
        return self._bar



    def do_that(given: A):
        x = given.get_foo()
        x += 10
        y = given.get_bar()

        y[0] += ' there'

        y = ['cool']

        given = A(-10, ['bye'])


x = A(1, ['boo'])
print(x.get_foo())
print(x.get_bar())
do_that(x)
print(x.get_foo())
print(x.get_bar())
```

Can someone explain why this is the output? Where does ['boo there'] come from and the 1 right before that?

```
1
['boo']
1
['boo there']
```

Comment: _"Where does ['boo there'] come from and the 1 right before that?"_ I'm confused. You know you're printing `x.get_foo()` and `x.get_bar()`, right? I thought you were asking "Why does it print `boo there` instead of `boo`?", but why on earth would you be surprised by that `1` being printed?

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are seeing is that in your `do_that` function, you are getting `x` and `y` from `self._foo` and `self._bar`.  You modify both local variables.  But when you print them out again, only `self._bar` changed.

The reason for this is that in python, the `list` type is mutable (can be changed), where the `int` type is immutable (and can only be replaced).

This means that when you get the `y` to `self._bar` and add `"there"` to element `[0]`, it is actually changing the list value held by the `self._bar` attribute.

But since `self._foo` is just an immutable value type, then assigning it to variable `x` and changing `x` will only result in `x` changing, not the original `self._foo`.

Proper programming would have you say `self._foo += 10` if you want to change the instance attribute.

Comment: `int` is not special in being passed by value. Pass by value/reference is the wrong distinction to make here.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `y = given.get_bar()` in the `do_that()` method it `get_bar()` actually return the reference of the `_bar` list reference. As list is mutable so it passed by reference.

And when you do the operation  `y[0] += ' there'` it actually change the `_bar` list as y is the reference of `_bar` and its mutable and becomes `['boo there']`. But when you do `y = ['cool']` it actually create a new list reference hence `_bar` previous reference lost. So it will not change the `_bar` anymore.

As a result after returning from the `do_that()` method when you call `x.get_bar()` it gives the result `['boo there']`

Comment: Mutability doesn’t affect whether anything is passed by reference. In Python, all values are “references” and they’re always passed by value.

Comment: Yes off course. As list is mutable so changing its value does not create new reference in memory. But in immutable type object changing its value will create new reference.

Comment: No, the behaviour is the same regardless of whether the type is mutable.

Comment: @Ryan sorry I did not get the point. :( As far I understand changing mutable object does not create new reference in memory but changing immutable does. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: You’re using two different meanings of “change”. In one, you change the object. Immutable objects can’t be changed by definition, so the two behave the same. In another, you change the variable. In this case, both also behave the same.